# Illegal Characters In Path Mystery

Tags: c#, .net, exception, wix, .net-2.0

This question might be quite localised, but I really need another opinion on what I'm doing wrong here. How can I be passing illegal characters in a path to a temporary file when at every stage of the process, everything appears to be fine and normal?

I'm getting this:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
```

When passing this:

`"C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Temp\1\tmp1E0.tmp"`

to this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(<above string>);
```

The file exists in the location specified (I've checked it during execution) although `System.IO.File.Exists` thinks otherwise; I cannot see anything obvious. Is there anything I could try to work around it?

More code available upon request:

**REQ1:** *How is your path being declared?*

```
try
{
    session.TempConfigDir = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
    //All work done with the temp file happens within the Form
    Form currentform = new WelcomeDialog(session);
    DialogResult dr = currentform.ShowDialog();
}
finally
{
    File.Delete(session.TempConfigDir);
}
```

The session variable is passed around to various locations, but is not altered.

**REQ2:** *Are you actually using `<username>`?*

No, I edited it out. It's a valid windows username.

**REQ3:** *What do you get back from debugging?*

This is actually happening within an installer (which is slightly difficult to physically debug) but the above string is an example from what I can get from the logs, with the valid username, of course.

**REQ4:** *More code on how it's used?*

I'm adding the WiX tag because this involves WiX3.7.

Basic Data holding class:

```
public class SessionState
{
    //<other properties>
    public string TempConfigDir { get; set; }

    public SessionState()
    {
        //Setting of properties
    }
}
```

From within the Form:

```
//StringBuilder for arguments
installerargs.Append("\" TEMPCONFIGDIR=\"");
installerargs.Append(m_Session.TempConfigDir);
//...
Process p = Process.Start("msiexec", installerargs.ToString());
p.WaitForExit();
```

*APPEND: Part missed from Form:*

```
//It's grabbing the web.config from an existing install
//and copying it over the temp file, not changing its location or name.
File.Copy(m_Session.INSTALLDIR + DIR_WEB_CONFIG, m_Session.TempConfigDir, true);
```

From within WiX3.7's MSI:

```
<Property Id="TEMPCONFIGDIR" Value="UNSET" />
```

...

```
<Custom Action="CA_InstallUICA.SetProp" After="StartServices">NOT Installed</Custom>
<Custom Action="CA_InstallUICA" After="CA_InstallUICA.SetProp">NOT Installed</Custom>
```

...

```
<CustomAction Id="CA_InstallUICA.SetProp" Property="CA_InstallUICA" Value="rcswebdir=[MCWSVDIR];webdir=[WEBAPPVDIR];installtype=notransaction;targetdir=[INSTALLDIR];interaction=[INTERACTION];tempconfigdir=&quot;[TEMPCONFIGDIR]&quot;;" />
```

From Within the Custom Action that uses it:

```
wz.AutoSettings.TempConfigLocation = session.CustomActionData["tempconfigdir"];
//Where I get the above string passed out
session.Log(wz.AutoSettings.TempConfigLocation);
//The rest of the code that uses it is above and where the exception is thrown
```

**REQ5:** *Do you change the TempConfigDir variable to something.xml?*

No, I copy an xml file over the exact name/directory that's supplied (including `.tmp`).

**REQ6:** *Are you sure it's happening on .Load()?*

Yes, I've logged each side of the line and only hit the first one when executing.

Comment: try this: @"C:\Documents and Settings\SRanson\Local Settings\Temp\1\tmp1E0.tmp"

Comment: I assume your string doesn't actually contain "<username>", since ">" and "<" are invalid characters in path ;)

Comment: @VictorMukherjee: I thought about this, but in reality, that string wouldn't even compile anyway as it would have unrecognized escape sequences (\D, \S, \L, \T, \1)

Comment: No, that's not it. If he hadn't escaped it, he would get a compiler error about an unrecognized escape sequence, so there's something else wrong. What is the username in question? You did remember to insert the username, right? You're not *actually* sending in `<username>`? That would actually produce that exception.

Comment: Have you debugged with a breakpoint and verified the _actual path_ you are feeding into `doc.Load()`?

Comment: Note that `File.Exists` when passing in `...<username>...` will in fact return false, whereas `XmlDocument.Load` will throw that exception. My guess is thus that you have forgotten to actually replace `<username>` with the actual username, hoping the system will do it for you.

Comment: If your file path is being created directly as a result of `Path.GetTempFileName()` then I'm not sure what is going on. Have you debugged and confirmed that you are not transforming/modifying that path by the time you hit `doc.Load` with it?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `TempConfigDir` as well as the code that uses it to load the document, ie. more of the code involved here?

Comment: If this exception is happening from an installer how can you be sure the exception is raised from the xmlDoc.Load() method?

Comment: How is it that the path has the "\1\" directory to it? Normally calls to `Path.GetTempFileName()` return the path to a temp file directly within the "\Temp\" directory, not a subdirectory. EDIT: Are your logs reporting the actual path being fed into the `Load` method or just the higher-level calls/usage?

Comment: Code posted, Sorry there's quite a bit to sift through.

Comment: Curious:  you have `session.TempConfigDir`, but fill it with a full path to a file, not a directory.  Is this significant?

Comment: @DonBoitnott It gives me a "placeholder" file that I overwrite with the actual file I want to keep.

Comment: This makes me wonder: `tempconfigdir=&quot;[TEMPCONFIGDIR]&quot;`...is the path already quoted, thus doubling the quotes? Or getting more quotes on the command line call?

Comment: @DonBoitnott I think I've tried that before, but it ended up only passing `C:\Documents`, I'll double check though (building takes a short while)

Comment: @DonBoitnott You got it! Post as answer? Now logs as (e.g.) `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Temp\1\tmp1E6.tmp` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line seems suspect:

```
<CustomAction Id="CA_InstallUICA.SetProp" Property="CA_InstallUICA" Value="rcswebdir=[MCWSVDIR];webdir=[WEBAPPVDIR];installtype=notransaction;targetdir=[INSTALLDIR];interaction=[INTERACTION];tempconfigdir=&quot;[TEMPCONFIGDIR]&quot;;" />
```

The portion quoting the path appears likely to be doubling the quotes, thus producing the exception:

```
tempconfigdir=&quot;[TEMPCONFIGDIR]&quot;
```

Remove the `&quote;` wrapping to deliver the actual path:

```
tempconfigdir=[TEMPCONFIGDIR]
```